# document.querySelectorAll().click() works only for the first time

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, selectors-api

Could you tell me why code below works for the first time:

```
var hangoutButton = document.querySelectorAll("a[href='#shiny-tab-plot']");
hangoutButton[0].click();
```

but when I execute it for the second time it returns error:

```
VM174:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined
```

Here are logs from firefox console:

```
var hangoutButton = document.querySelectorAll("a[href='#shiny-tab-plot']");
undefined
hangoutButton[0].click();
undefined
shiny-server-client.min.js:1 Wed Aug 09 2017 12:42:16 GMT+0200 (CEST) [DBG]: 1 message(s) discarded from buffer
var hangoutButton = document.querySelectorAll("a[href='#shiny-tab-plot']");
undefined
hangoutButton[0].click();
VM174:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined
    at <anonymous>:1:17
(anonymous) @ VM174:1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check, if something was found! If not, `undefined` is returned. And of course you can not call `click()` on `undefined`.

```
var hangoutButton = document.querySelectorAll("a[href='#shiny-tab-plot']");
if(hangoutButton && hangoutButton.length)
{
   hangoutButton[0].click();
}
```

Otherwise if you want only the first element, you can shorten it by

```
var hangoutButton = document.querySelector("a[href='#shiny-tab-plot']");
if(hangoutButton)
{
   hangoutButton.click();
}
```

Comment: OK, but why is returned object changing after 1st execution? I tried with jQuery and when I execute `var x = $("a[href='#shiny-tab-Datatab']");` i got object: `[a, prevObject: n.fn.init(1), context: document, selector: "a[href='#shiny-tab-Datatab']"]` and after second execution i got: `[prevObject: n.fn.init(1), context: document, selector: "a[href='#shiny-tab-Datatab']"]`?

Comment: Do you run the querySelector again? Or are you still working with the "old" result?

Comment: Running what again? Click, Query, or both? It would be easier to help if you extend your example.

Comment: OK, let's stay with pure javascript. Every time I run this function: https://jsfiddle.net/Tazovsky/uyu0vLba/1/ For the first time it works - for second it's not.